# Email etiquette - should I respond with "thanks" in this situation?

Tags: professionalism, email

I needed to be granted access to some IT resource by a colleague, so I sent a short email like this:

> Hi *colleague*,
>
> I need access to *blah*, could you please add me to the permitted user list?
>
> Thanks,
>
> *me*

Shortly he did what I asked for, and I received a one-liner containing literally

> done

This colleague is quite a busy person, and I'm certain his email inbox is overflowing as it is. I don't want to appear rude by not sending a quick "Thanks" message, but I also don't want to add more clutter to his inbox.

Would it be appropriate *not* to send "Thanks"?

I probably need to add that it's not his primary job to grant access to stuff; he's the creator/owner of the resource, this is why he needs to explicitly allow people to use it.

Comment: @Brandin not a duplicate.  Linked question was closed as off-topic, this is about a response, not a closing expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> should I respond with “thanks” in this situation?

Based on my experience, in this case there is no need to send an additional email.  As you said, this individual is busy, and was simply informing you that what you asked for was done. You already implied the "Thanks" part in your first email's signature.

If the email included some additional useful information or special instructions you may want to consider a thank you response for that.

Short answer:  **No response required** in this case.

Answer (score 9):

Yes respond. As soon as you have verified that you have actually been given the access you requested. I have seen people click the wrong button, or click the wrong name and it has to be done again.

The response should be on the order of:

"I'm in. Thanks for your help."

That lets them know that you have actually used the access that you requested. It is never a good feeling when you drop everything for an urgent request, and then you find out that they never even accessed the system.

Comment: I second this answer because, unless you know that person well, never assume that someone does not pay attention to the fact that you did or did not say "thank you". If you don't, he may remember you as the one he helped out though very busy, and didn't even drop a quick thank you line. On the other hand, if he isn't that type of person, saying thank you still doesn't hurt anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Don´t respond. He is busy and you will clutter his inbox. If he cared for niceties, he would have sent you more than a "done". The whole matter is already out of his mind.

Next time you mail him about something else, you can thank him in the open line. *Thank you for completing my other task so fast. This really helped me a lot. ... say what you want to say ...*